# How to make videos play on mouseover and pause on mouseout in Angular 9?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have found some example for HTML5 like `controls loop onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause();"` but it doesn't work in Angular 9 template.
I think, I need add some method in component like:

```
  over(): void {
    //TODO
  }

  out(): void {
    //TODO
  }
```

and then add in template:

```
    <div style='width:100%;height:100%' align="center" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()">
      <iframe src="..." style='min-width: 30%; height: 315px' allowfullscreen
              (mouseover)='over()' (mouseout)='out()'
        >
      </iframe>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I don't have idea how to implement the both methods in the component, so that my video will play the player from my link.

Comment: I see you're embedding, so first of all: do you plan on using a specific video platform provider (such as YouTube, Vimeo, etc...) or will this be too dynamic to know?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Generally it will be dynamically, in the app should exist many types of video (not only 1 type like youtube). I have seen the play on mouseoverview is working on the sites, where the links come from.

Comment: Oh, I see... Because I had to create custom controls for a project that uses embed and local videos but at least we have the list of possible providers, so I just made it to recognize where does the video come from (maybe deduce it from the url or just add a field where you specify the platform), and depending on its type I set up the proper API (HTML, YouTube, Vimeo...)

Hope this gives you and idea and maybe helps.